Show $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^n (k + 1)} = \frac{1}{4}$
Claim
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^n (k + 1)} = \frac{1}{4}
$$
Proof
Using these identities:

$\frac{1}{k+1} = \int_{0}^{1} x^k \, dx$
$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k^n} = \frac{x^k}{k(k-1)}$
$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{(k-1)k} = (1 - x)\ln(1 - x) + x$

Then,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^n (k+1)} &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^k}{k^n} \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k^n} \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k(k-1)} \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \left[ (1 - x)\ln(1 - x) + x \right] \, dx \\
&= \underbrace{ \int_{0}^{1} (1 - x)\ln(1 - x) \, dx }_{=\, -\frac{1}{4}} + \underbrace{ \int_{0}^{1} x \, dx }_{=\, \frac{1}{2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}
Question
WolframAlpha shows the same result but not the steps taken.
Are there other easier methods to arrive at the same interesting result?

Telescoping series works directly. Show that the inner summation is $ 1/ (k(k^2 - 1) )$ and thus the outer summation is $1/2 - 1/4 = 1/4$.

Thanks. Just noticed the double summation can be rewritten simpler as $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}   \frac{1}{(k-1),k,(k+1)}$$ WolframAlpha

Yeah there's a geometric series

Geometric series, partial fractions, and telescoping:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^n (k + 1)} 
&= \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k + 1} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^n \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k + 1} \cdot \frac{(1/k)^2}{1-1/k} \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)k(k-1)} \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1/2}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1/2}{k-1}\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1/2}{k+1}-\frac{1/2}{k}\right)-\left(\frac{1/2}{k}-\frac{1/2}{k-1}\right)\right] \\
&= -\left(\frac{1/2}{2}-\frac{1/2}{2-1}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}
\end{align}
